# Code behind not executing for custom control libraries

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls, code-behind

I created a custom user control library. I created an empty Web Application using Visual Studio 2012 and placed inside it a custom user control with the following top line in the ascx file.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" ClassName="MyControls.HelloWorld" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HelloWorld.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyControls.Controls.HelloWorld" %>
```

The purpose of explicitly stating the ClassName as such is so that the main website application can load / use the custom controls. Naturally, there is a code behind file. For whatever it is worth, there is a DevExpress callback panel with a C# code behind event handler.

I build and then publish the MyControls library using

- Precompile during publishing
- (configure) Merge all outputs to a single assembly
- (does not matter, but I have "Treat as library component..." checked.
- I set the name to MyControlsLib

(Why checked, because checked or unchecked, there is the same problem.)

I create a website, MyWebsite, and add references to MyControls and MyControlsLib.

I then use LoadControl and specify the type of the control:

```
typeof (MyControls.HelloWorld)
```

I then proceed to display the user control. That works fine, no issues.

PROBLEM:
The problem is that the code behind does not execute. I get the error message:

```
The target $#39;ctl00$ctl00$cpDynamic$dpopHelloWorld$uc$cpHelloWorld&#39; for the callback could not be found or did not implement ICallbackEventandler.
```

That cryptic error message basically states that the runtime environment cannot find the code behind file. I am testing with debug environment (F5) from within Visual Studio using IE10 (under Windows 7). I set a breakpoint, which I do not hit.

I do need both references, as there is code behind in the MyControls.dll not pertaining to the user control that I use in the main application. The MyControlsLib.dll contains the user controls.

Although the actual article, whose method that I am using was a different MSDN article, the outline is similar [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2005/10/30/487160.aspx).

Why is the main asp.net website not finding the code behind?

Comment: I don't normally see loading a Custom Control like a Server Control. We normally load a Custom Control like - `var control = Page.LoadControl("./HelloWorld.ascx");` I might be wrong; could you post an article if your testing is based on the article?

Comment: I added a link to an MSDN article.